# MySQL query with 2 tables join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **users** like this:

```
id    username
1       user1
2       user2
3       user3
```

and a **msgs** like this:

```
t_id   sent_by   id    msg
1        2        1     whatever
2        3        1     is
3        2        1     here
```

Where **users.id** is a primary key and **msgs.id** is a foreign key. In the **msgs** table, **id** is the destination of the message sent by **sent_by**.

I want to select and display the **username** of **sent_by** as long as the logged in user (via sessions) is the **msgs.id**.

To clarify things, here is the pseudocode of what I wanted to do:

1. Users has logged in. Store its `userid` to `session`.
2. Display the distinct usernames of who sent me (the logged in user) the messages. In the example above, the display will be: `user2, user3` if I have a user id of 1.

I was thinking of using join but ended up doing 2 queries for the sent_by and ids. It seems not an efficient query.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a straightforward `JOIN` since you only wish to return usernames of the `sent_by` ids.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
    users.username
    msgs.sent_by
  FROM users JOIN msgs ON users.id = msgs.sent_by 
  WHERE id = {$_SESSION['my_userid']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, m.sent_by
FROM msgs m
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.sent_by
WHERE m.id = {$_SESSION['userid']}
ORDER BY m.t_id DESC
```